# Is append necessary for this jQuery.each script? And how can I prevent copies?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this script online and it works great my biggest problem is it haves append in this script. And I notice its making copies every time I press the button so how

can I prevent that and I want to use toggle to that same button to show and hide. So is append really necessary for this script? If not then what can I use instead

to give the outcome of using a toggle button to show and hide the objects contents with out outputting additional copies because of append? Here's the code.

```js
var data = { on_sale: [ 
                { 
                    name:"Red Mask", 
                    price:"$500" 
                }, 
                { 
                    name:"Blue Cape", 
                    price:"$200"
                } 
           ]};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(){

           $.each(data.on_sale, function (i) {
               $.each(data.on_sale[i], function (key, val) {
                   $("#x").append(val+"<br>").toggle();
               });
           });
  });
   });
```

```css
#x {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  background-color: gold;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="programs-header"></div>
<div class="container">
<h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = { on_sale: [ 
            { 
                name:"Red Mask", 
                price:"$500" 
            }, 
            { 
                name:"Blue Cape", 
                price:"$200"
            } 
       ]};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = $('#x');
  var output = '';
  $.each(data.on_sale, function (index, element) {
               output += element.name + '<br>' +element.price +'<br>';
           });
  console.log(output);
  x.html(output);
  $("button").click(function(){
    x.toggle();
    });
  });
```

Instead of filling x on click, you can fill it on document ready, and then you can just toggle x with .toggle().

If you want it to be invisible on first load, add

```
display: none;
```

to your css for x

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is validate the data your appending if it was already appended once(if you want it to be appended once), in this case I created a toggle to check if the data was appended already.

```
var isAppended = false;
var data = { on_sale: [ 
                { 
                    name:"Red Mask", 
                    price:"$500" 
                }, 
                { 
                    name:"Blue Cape", 
                    price:"$200"
                } 
           ]};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(){
        if(!isAppended){
           $.each(data.on_sale, function (i) {
               $.each(data.on_sale[i], function (key, val) {
                   $("#x").append(val+"<br>").toggle();
                   $("#x").show();
               });
           });
         isAppended = true;
        }else{
         //insert method here that hides and show the appended element like this
         var query = $('#x');
        if (query.is(':visible')) {
            query.hide();
        } else {
            query.show();
        }
   }
  });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify your js ,have a look:

```js
var data = { on_sale: [ 
                { 
                    name:"Red Mask", 
                    price:"$500" 
                }, 
                { 
                    name:"Blue Cape", 
                    price:"$200"
                } 
           ]};
var _html = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(){
       if (!_html) {
           $.each(data.on_sale, function (i) {
               $.each(data.on_sale[i], function (key, val) {
                   _html+= val+"<br>";
               });
           });
           $('#x').append(_html).show();
       } else {
           $('#x').toggle();
       }
  });
});
```

```css
#x {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  background-color: gold;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="programs-header"></div>
<div class="container">
<h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version, using **Array.map()** instead of **Array.each()**.

**For single key in `data` object:**

```js
var data = {on_sale: [{name: "Red Mask",price: "$500"},{name: "Blue Cape",price: "$200"}]};

$(document).ready(function () {
  var clicked = false; 
  $("button").on("click", function () {
    if (!clicked) //If button not clicked then add content to h2 tag
    {
      $("#x").html(data.on_sale.map(function(e) { return e.name + "<br/>" + e.price }).join("<br/>"));
      clicked = true;
    }
    else
      $("#x").toggle(); //toggle display
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  #x {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .container {
    background-color: gold;
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>
  
<div id="programs-header"></div>
<div class="container">
  <h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

**For multiple keys in `data` object:**

```js
var data = {
  on_sale: [{ name: "Red Mask", price: "$500" }, { name: "Blue Cape", price: "$200" }],
  on_sale1: [{ name: "Red Mask", price: "$500" }, { name: "Blue Cape", price: "$200" }]
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  var clicked = false;
  $("button").on("click", function () {
 if (!clicked) {
   var arr = [];
   Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
  arr.push(data[key].map(function (e) { return e.name + "<br/>" + e.price }).join("<br/>"));
   });
   $("#x").html(arr.join("<br/>"));
   clicked = true;
 }
 else
   $("#x").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#x {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: gold;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
  
<div id="programs-header"></div>
<div class="container">
 <h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```